# Can the Shillelagh cantrip be used with improvised clubs or quarterstaffs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, improvised-weaponry, cantrips

**If a druid were to pick up a wooden table leg used as an improvised club, or a tree branch small enough to be wielded as an improvised quarterstaff, could the druid use the *shillelagh* cantrip on the improvised club or quarterstaff?**

The [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) spell description says:

> The wood of a club or quarterstaff you are holding is imbued with
>   nature’s power. For the duration, you can use your spellcasting
>   ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee
>   attacks using that weapon, and the weapon's damage die becomes a d8.
>   The weapon also becomes magical, if it isn’t already. The spell ends
>   if you cast it again or if you let go of the weapon.

The spell description restricts the cantrip to clubs and quarterstaffs that are wooden, but says nothing about improvised clubs or quarterstaffs. If a weapon is improvised as either of those two weapons, and is also made of wood, might this cantrip be applied to the objects in question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Yes

An excerpt about [Improvised Weapons](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Weapons#toc_14):

> *Often, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such. For example, a table leg is akin to a club.*

A wooden table leg is an improvised weapon, but it is treated as a club from the description of improvised weapon. When treated as a club, it could then be used as a target for Shillelagh by the cantrip's description.

So you are able to use Shillelagh on an improvised weapon, as long as it is made of wood and resembles a club or a quarterstaff.

Comment: That’s actually an interesting catch. I asked a question a while ago about using the butt-end of a spear as a bludgeoning weapon and the answer on here was it gets just the d4 damage of an improvised weapon and so on, where this answer seems much more realistic.

Answer (score -4):

> **At the DM's option**, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar 
>   object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.

Enough said.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I think that Dale was implying that with a DM's caveat -- an improvised club is a club and thus yes, you could..although  A.B. I agree, it's not well formed as an answer...and yours is a much better answer

Comment: *Not* enough said. Say more.